# Inheriting generics with inherited parameterizations

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I am looking for a way to inherit generics with inherited parameterizations - or if that's not possible, the closest way to get the same functionality.

Consider the following:

Class B inherits from class A

Class D inherits from Class C

Now, I have one class:

```
abstract class A<T> where T : C
```

with constructor:

```
public A(T t)
```

Now, I wish to extend class A as so:

```
class B<D> : A<C>
```

Creating a constructor:

```
 public B(D t) : base(t){ /*stuff here*/}
```

However, this throws a compile-time error, since D is not C.  So my two questions are:

a) Is there a clean way to do this?  In the worst case scenario, I think I can replace D with C with little problem, but maybe there's a reason why that's not a safe idea?

b) Should I even be explicitly stating my generics in the child class definition, or is there a cleaner way I should do this with constrained types?

Comment: Don't really see the scenario you'd use it, but `A<T1, T2> where T1 : T2 where T2 : C` and `B<D> : A<D, C>` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a where constraint to class B

```
class B<D> : A<C> where D : C
```

To answer you questions:

a) With the fix in this answer, your approach is pretty clean so far, if a tad over abstract (due to the names mostly).

b) You should only be adding the D generic type parameter to your child class B if the child class itself is either adding value in a generic way related to subclasses of C which are instances of D; or if the child class is itself incomplete, is expected to be extended and requires knowledge subclasses of C as D.  In which case, you should mark it abstract.

**UPDATE**:

I wanted to add one more thing about this.  In the signature above, the `T` parameter of `A<T>` will be C in those members of A that use the `T` type.  This may be a problem as demonstrated in the following example:

```
public class C {}

public class F : C {}

public class E : C {}

public class A<T> where T : C
{
    protected T cSubclass;
    public void SetCSubclass(T cSubclass) { this.cSubclass = cSubclass; }
}

public class B<D> : A<C> where D : C
{
    public D GetCSubclass()
    {
        return this.cSubclass;
    }
}
```

The code in this example will not compile.  You will get the following compilation error:

```
error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'C' to 'D'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

However the compilation error is resolved if we change class B to the following:

```
public class B<D> : A<D> where D : C
{
    public D GetCSubclass()
    {
        return this.cSubclass;
    }
}
```

The reason is that D is to be a specific subclass of C, however in the former version we've only constrained A to any form of C including itself and any of its subclasses.  Therefore we could potentially call `new B<F>.SetCSubclass(new E());` which would be a different type then what GetCSubclass would be expecting to return.  In the latter version we've specified D as the type argument to use in A forcing `B<F>.SetCSubclass` to only accept instances of `F`.

This provides a further degree of type safety that a developer using this type of pattern may be expecting.

Comment: @user650261 I wanted to add one more thing about this.  Are you sure that you don't want "class B<D> : A<D> where D : C {}". The difference with this alternate signature is that anywhere A returns or accepts T in subclasses of B, T will be D.  In the signature provided in my answer, T will be C in those members of A which may not be what you ultimately want, since if T is used for a method parameter, you may end up receiving a subclass of C that is not a subclass of D.